# Dependency resolution for classes with same package structure in Gradle

Tags: java, gradle, dependencies, dependency-resolution

Say I have a project `ProjectA` with a compile dependency on `core`. And `core` depends on `deepcore`. Thus, ProjectA has a transitive dependency on deepcore.

So, build script for `ProjectA` has this

```
dependencies {
    compile "com.something:core:1.0.0"
}
```

And build script for `core` has this

```
dependencies {
    compile "com.something:deep-core:1.0.0"
}
```

Now, there is a class `CoreService` defined in both `core` and `deepcore` with the same package structure. And I am using that class from my `ProjectA`, which implementation will it use? How do configure my dependency so that I am using the version from `core`?

Comment: If you think this is not a valid question, could you please point me to related documentation where dependency ordering for gradle is explained. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you are looking for.

```
dependencies {
    compile "com.something:deep-core:1.0.0" {
      exclude group: 'com.unwanted', module: 'unwanted'
    }
}
```